# persisting error with latex caption.sty ubuntu 14.04

Tags: pdftex, captions

edit: I know that my Tex Live version is outdated (2013). In order to get an  upgrade I did:

```
sudo apt remove --purge tex-common '^texlive'
sudo rm -rf ~/.texlive*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2018
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
```

and checked the log file of a newly compiled document. It's still 2013 version. What do I need to do to get rid of the old version?

So I got two machines and need to be able to compile the same .tex files on both machines.

1. ubuntu 14.04
2. freshly installed lubuntu 18.04 on thinkpad x220

On machine 2. it's always been working, on machine 1 there has always been this problem with caption.sty - I could not find anything helpful in the existing threads.

The error is:

```
[PDFLatex] finished with exit code 1
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/caption.sty:772:Command \caption@box already defined. ..pt{\caption@ibox{#1}{#2}}]\wd\@tempboxa}}
/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/caption.sty:972:Command \caption@addsubcontentslines already defined. \caption@clearsubcontentslines}
```

My preamble (sorry for the mess):

```
\documentclass[pdftex,A4,10pt]{article}
% \usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[font=small,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
% \usepackage{capt-of}
% \usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{natbib} 
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{marginnote}
% \usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\jot}{10pt}
\usepackage[top=1.6cm,bottom=1.6cm,inner=2cm,outer=6cm,marginparsep=1cm,marginparwidth=4cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand*\Diff[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d^#1}}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
\lstset{ 
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
}
\raggedbottom
\newcommand\tab[1][0.5cm]{\hspace*{#1}}


\begin{document}


blabla \\
\end{document}
```

log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2019.2.10)  10 FEB 2019 19:24
```

Comment: Out of all distros I have ever used, 14.04 has just worked like a charm. I thought with ESM there is no problem in using it further. Just spend three days wrestling with new installation on machine 2. Doing a complete system upgrade in order to solve such a minor problem is not an option for me.

Comment: That is Tex Live 2015/Debian. Thing is I just purged texlive on both machines and reinstalled with apt install texlive-latex-extra.

Comment: I'm just trying to remove the old Tex Live on machine 1. It does not sit in /usr/local as it says here https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html but in /usr/share . Will removing all the files in there get me ready for doing a new installation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89526/discussion-between-michael-and-kurt).